# Check if path is desired result in react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

So I'm trying to hide certain elements if the path in react router is a desired result. For example, when a user goes to settings, the path would be

```
<NavHashLink to='/settings'></NavHashLink >
```

But also if a user clicks on another link which is inside the settings, the hidden elements should still stay hidden, for example,

```
<NavHashLink to='/settings/account'></NavHashLink>
```

Any idea how to do so?
Elements to hide: Navbar, etc

Comment: Can you explain what a "desired result" is, and what should be hidden? BTW you are showing us the links to a path, but not what is rendered by a path matched `Route`.

Comment: In the example, the desired result would be settings, basically want to hide the navbar and maybe other elements when the user is in the settings page

Comment: Do you mean, you want to hide the link to a page if the app is currently rendering that page (or any sub-route)?

Comment: Hiding the element isnt hard as long as i can be able to get a boolean value if the user is in the settings page

Comment: Which would contain anything that starts in /settings

Comment: What have you tried already? You could render the link into a route and use the route props to conditionally render the link, or use the link's active style to conditionally hide itself.

Comment: Interesting , that gave me an idea